# How to generate heatmap inside the for loop?

Tags: python, heatmap

I have the following for loop that traverses through a folder of CSV files and performs some computations. This computation is done between one to one file computation like `file1.csv versus file2.csv`, and `file1.csv versus file3.csv` and so on.

I am now able to save the outputs of the computation into CSV file with a specific folder but I am also trying to generate the heatmap for each computation, for example, `file1.csv vs file2.csv` and save the figure into a specific path that I want. I can generate the heatmap only for 2 files computation but when I am want to do it in following for loop, it is saving all the results into only one figure:

Here is the code

```
# read the files
for dirName, subdirList, Myfile in os.walk(path):
    print('Directory: %s' % dirName)
    for files in Myfile:
        print('\t%s' % files)

# apply one to one compuattion between the files
for i in range(len(Myfile)):
    print(Myfile)
    for j in range(i+1, len(Myfile)):

        CSV1 = pd.read_csv(path+'/'+Myfile[i], error_bad_lines=False);
        CSV2 = pd.read_csv(path+'/'+Myfile[j], error_bad_lines=False);

        df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=f1)
        df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=f2)

        result = calculate_stock(df1, df2)  
        # generate the heatmaps for heach one to one computation
        ax = sns.heatmap(result, linewidth=0.5)
        # save the figure
        figure = ax.get_figure() 
        figure.savefig('svm_conf.png', dpi=400)      

        result.to_csv(path+'/'+ Myfile[i]+'_versus_'+ Myfile[j],index=True)
```

when i try as following:

```
figure.savefig(path+'/'+ Myfile[i]+'_versus_'+Myfile[j], format='png', index=True)
```

It saves a file as CSV, not png file and inside the CSV is full of random alphabets.

It would be great if you can let me know how I can fix this issue.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I edit the post. It saving as csv file, not a png or any figure.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the format parameter is not working well. Please use the code below.

```
figure.savefig(path+'/'+ Myfile[i]+'_versus_'+Myfile[j]+'.png')
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried your code. the output figure is overlapped results of all the heatmaps. Is there any issue in my for loop that I am getting like this?